# Затранскрибируйте текст

Tags: фонетика

под голубыми небесами
великолепными коврами,
блестя на солнце, снег лежит;
прозрачный лес один чернеет,
и ель  сквозь иней зеленеет, 
и речка подо льдом блестит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Транскрипция школьная или студенческая?

[пъдгълубыми   н’ьб’и(с призвуком э)сам’и  в’ьл’икΛл’эпным’и  кΛврам’и/  бл’иэс’т’а   нΛсонц  /   с’н’эк   ли(э)жыт/    прΛзрач’ный  л’эс     Λд’ин    ч’и(э)рн’эjьт/     и    jэл’   cквъс’ин’ьй   з'ьли(э)н’эj’ьт/     и р’эч’къ    пъд Λл’дом    бл’и(э)с’т’ит ]

Если школьный - вместо Λ -а, вместо и(э)-просто И.

Comment: [нΛсонцЪ], [cквΛс’ин’ьй'], [ч’и(э)рн’эj'ьт],[ыj'эл’]

Comment: [cквΛс’ин’ьй']- согласна, была невнимательна, первый предударный -крышечка .
 [нΛсонцЪ]- Е и Э в заударных после твёрдых согласных звука нет, посмотрите в таблицу.  При палатальном [j]  не принято ставить мягкость (апостроф).Вместо Й должен быть i cо знаком неслогового внизу, я просто не стала усложнять.
и-jэл’- в честь чего И в абсолютном начале перед мягким звуком j превратилась в Ы? Попробуйте произнести, она не меняется.Это же не после твёрдых.

Comment: "блестя" = [c]ъ, вроде, твердый, нет?
"сквозь иней" - з не оглушается: [сквΛз'иниj], оглушалось бы в произнесении [сквΛс'jыниj].

Comment: 1.Согласные С и З смягчаются перед мягкими [т'] и [д']
2.насчёт [сквΛс'jын'ьj], может, Вы и правы, только я произношу мягко, c И, но всё равно слышится С.
3.В таблице слабых гласных фонем написано, что после твёрдого согласного звука нет. Только вот я не учла, что это в абсолютном конце, значит,[ ъ].

Comment: Людмила, да покажите же, наконец, эту таблицу.     
~1. "Блестя" я точно произношу с твердым С, но допускаю ненормативность.  
~2. Так дело не в мягкости, а в наличии/отсутвии пауза между "...зь" и "ин.."
~3. OK

Comment: На этом сайте рисовать таблицы не умею, у меня она в "Современном русском"Валгиной и в методичках, в Интернете даже искать не буду. Так что ничем помочь не могу.

Comment: Ясно. Будем считать источник невоспроизводимым. 
А хотелось бы посмотреть, где такое пишут.